# Bootstrap Nav Dropdown Not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for rails. I downloaded the bootstrap.min and reg bootstrap files into my rails app. I'm creating a dropdown menu but for some reason I'm unable to click on it and display the dropdown.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="navbar-wrapper logo">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">compnay logo</a>
          <div id="navbar" class="secondary">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class='secondary-nav'><%= link_to 'Log Out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dashboards <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

I tried to see if this was a jQuery not loading to execute. But that wasn't it as I was able to perform $(".navbar") and get a result back. I'm not sure what it is at this point. I feel lost and would appreciate any help.

[Edit]
Add application.js to show jquery is loading first.

```
   //= require jquery
   //= require jquery_ujs
   //= require bootstrap.min
   //= require turbolinks
   //= require_tree .
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this (http://www.bootply.com/RbKgKsoJnM), are you loading jQuery before Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to download the .js files like bootstrap-dropdown.js and add it to your assets.

And in your application.js

```
//= require bootstrap-dropdown.js
```

just before

```
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: I downloaded the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js that contains bootstrap-dropdown

Comment: what is your rails version ? if 4 did you try what i suggested ?

Comment: I'm using Rails 4. I followed your suggestion and the dropdown is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import bootstrap in your application.js:

```
//= require bootstrap
```